# Split String into alpha & punctuation with exceptions regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to split a string into 2 parts : alphanum chars & special chars. I want to limit the occurence of the escape character

> b.sc.... = ['b.sc.','...'] (Preserve "." inside word & outside word just once)

> really???? = ['really','????'] (split when any other special char encountered)

I went through a lot of SO questions before posting here. I have come up with this till now: `re.findall(r"[\w+|\-.+\w]+|\W+`,text)`
How to proceed further?

Comment: `hello. What about this?` - can I ask the output of this?

Comment: should be `['hello.', 'What', 'about', 'this', '?']`

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'\w+(?:-\w+)+|(?:\w+\.)+|\w+|\W+', text)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/SHqdy9/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This works partially - given the string "k-11" I get ["k11"] - that's all good. How can I also make sure to limit the occurence of `-` or `.` to just 1. So that given `"k---11"` I get `["k-11"]` & not `["k", "--", "11"]`

Comment: `[\w+|\-.+\w]+` is totally wrong, you placed sequences into a character class.

Comment: You want `[re.sub(r'([.-])+', r'\1', x) for x in re.findall(r'\w+(?:-+\w+)+|(?:\w+(?:\.+(?=\w)|\.))+|\w+|[^\w\s]+', text)]`, don't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
[re.sub(r'([.-])+', r'\1', x) for x in re.findall(r'\w+(?:-+\w+)+|\w+(?:\.+\w+)*\.?|[^\w\s]+', text)]
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mGAgPg/3)

**Details**

- `\w+(?:-+\w+)+` - one or more word chars followed with one or more occurrences of `-` and one or more word chars
- `|` - or
- `\w+(?:\.+\w+)*\.?` - one or more word chars followed with one or more occurrences of `.` and one or more word chars and then an optional dot
- `|` - or
- `[^\w\s]+` - one or more non-word and non-whitespace chars.

The `re.sub(r'([.-])+', r'\1', x)` part is a post-processing step to replace one or more consecutive `.` or `-` chars with a single occurrence.

Comment: How can I extend this to ensure that `b.sc` results in `['b.sc']`  and `b.sc.` results in `['b.sc.']` i.e both cases in one regex

Comment: @xerxes01 Maybe `\w+(?:-+\w+)+|\w+(?:\.+\w+)*\.?|[^\w\s]+`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mGAgPg/3).